# xubuntu 12.04 Thunar deletes files with permission r--r--r--. Is it a bug?

Tags: xubuntu, files, chmod, thunar

I tried to prevent my digital photos (.jpg files) from accidental deletion using
chmod 444 *.jpg. All permissions are set and displayed correctly in a terminal (ls -la) as well as in thunar's file properties > permissions. The files are displayed with a lock symbol.
Even though, whenever I press "delete", the marked file is moved to trash.
My expectation was that files without write permission could not be moved to trash.
Is it a bug or am I just wrong assuming that moving a file requires write permission?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Nautilus behaves the same (as does bash terminal).  You can delete a read-only file, because it is the *directory* permissions that control that operation.  In theory, you can't write to a read-only file, although many editors will delete the original (or make a backup), then write to a new file, so it seems that you can write to the read-only file.

If you were to make the permissions for a directory r-x, then you would not be able to delete any files (but you could still write to the files, assuming they are **not** read-only).